# how to create a 3D image of the damaged area of Skull?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, vtk, itk

I have been given a task to create the damaged area of a skull in 3D so that it can be used to 3D print and then use for the surgery to cover the damaged skull area.

So what I want to do is to get the 3D image of the damaged area of the skull. So that I can 3D print it.

I have been given a set of CT images of a subject with a damaged skull and a large area of the left side of the skull is damaged. I can use any software to do the processing and viewing.

I selected vtk and itk kits together with visual studio to do the processing and Slicer to view it in 3D.

I want to know whether there is any methodology to follow in this particular scenario and what would be the best way to extract the damaged area form the given set of CT images.

I really appreciate if anyone can give any ideas or if there is any standard method in practice. Please recommend a method together with software kits best for this work.

thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to 3d print the damaged area, ultimately you will need some kind of mesh representation of it. I suggest the following steps:

Threshold the CT scan in ITK: http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BinaryThresholdImageFilter.html

Crop the region around the damaged skull that you want using an ITK crop filter.

Save the resultant 3d image as a binary representation of the skull, in, say, nifti format, and then run marching cubes on it to get a surface representation:
http://www.itk.org/Doxygen46/html/Filtering_2SurfaceExtraction_8cxx-example.html

Load the mesh up in slicer to check that it looks ok.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir. I will try this out and let you know. Thanks again!!

Comment: hey, I tried to threshold a CT image and was succeeded in doing that. Now i want to save the file as a diacom file So that i can apply new set of operation to that saved file. Do you know how to do this? I tried Vtk writer classes, but those saved files are not really diacom like my original image file. I would reaaly appreciate if you can give me any clue. Thanks!